# Caching and reusing a function result in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have an expensive function to include in my Tornado app. The function
returns several outputs but, for legacy reason, these outputs are accessed
separately through different handlers.

Is there a way to execute the function only once, re-use the result for the
different handlers and preserve Tornado's asynchronous behavior?

```
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
from tonado.ioloop import IOLoop

# the expensive function
def add(x, y):
    z = x + y
    return x, y, z

# the handlers that reuse the function
class Get_X(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, x, y):
        x, y, z = add(x, y) 
        return x

class Get_Y(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, x, y):
        x, y, z = add(x, y) 
        return y

class Get_Z(RequestHandler):
    def get(self, x, y):
        x, y, z = add(x, y) 
        return z

# the web service
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/Get_X', Get_X),
    (r'/Get_Y', Get_Y),
    (r'/Get_Z', Get_Z),
])

application.listen(8888)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

I thought about about caching the result of the function in a dictionary, but I'm not sure on how to make the two other handlers wait, while the first one creates a dictionary entry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tornado `Futures` are reusable, so you can simply save the `Future` before yielding it. Many off-the-shelf caching decorators (like python 3.2's `functools.lru_cache` will just work if you put them in front of `@gen.coroutine`:

```
import functools
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=100)
@gen.coroutine
def expensive_function():
    print('starting expensive_function')
    yield gen.sleep(5)
    return 1, 2, 3

@gen.coroutine
def get_x():
    print('starting get_x')
    x, y, z = yield expensive_function()
    return x

@gen.coroutine
def get_y():
    print('starting get_y')
    x, y, z = yield expensive_function()
    return y

@gen.coroutine
def get_z():
    print('starting get_z')
    x, y, z = yield expensive_function()
    return z

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    x, y, z = yield [get_x(), get_y(), get_z()]
    print(x, y, z)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

Prints:

```
starting get_x
starting expensive_function
starting get_y
starting get_z
finished expensive_function
1 2 3
```

Comment: Hi Ben, your answer looks like a great solution to what I'm looking for. I have posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680671/combine-tornado-gen-coroutine-and-joblib-mem-cache-decorators) and will be glad if you could have a look and share your thoughts. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're concerned about one handler taking time to calculate a value to be placed in the cache, while other handlers wait for the value to appear in the cache.

Tornado 4.2 includes an [Event](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/stable/locks.html#event) class you can use to coordinate the coroutines that want the cached value. When a handler wants to get a value from the cache, it checks if the cached value is there:

```
from tornado import locks

class Get_X(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self, x, y):
        key = (x, y, 'Get_X')
        if key in cache:
            value = cache[key]
            if isinstance(value, locks.Event):
                # Another coroutine has begun calculating.
                yield value.wait()
                value = cache[key]

            self.write(value)
            return

        # Calculate the value.
        cache[key] = event = locks.Event()
        value = calculate(x, y)
        cache[key] = value
        event.set()
        self.write(value)
```

This code is untested.

In real code, you should wrap `calculate` in a try / except that clears the Event from the cache if `calculate` fails. Otherwise, all other coroutines will wait forever for the Event to be set.

I assume `calculate` returns a string you can pass to `self.write`. In your application there might be further processing with the value before you can call `self.write` or `self.render`.

You should also consider how large your cache might grow: how large are values, and how many distinct keys will there be? You may need a bounded cache that evicts the least-recently-used value; there are plenty of search results for "Python LRU cache", you might [try Raymond Hettinger's](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577970-simplified-lru-cache/?in=user-178123) since he's widely respected.

For a more sophisticated example of RequestHandlers using Events to synchronize around a cache, see [my proxy example in the Toro documentation](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples/event_example.html). It's far from a full-featured web proxy, but the example is written to demonstrate a solution to the exact problem you present: how to avoid duplicate work when calculating a value to be placed in the cache.