# Combine tornado gen.coroutine and joblib mem.cache decorators

Tags: asynchronous, tornado, coroutine, joblib

Imagine having a function, which handles a heavy computational job, that we wish to execute asynchronously in a Tornado application context. Moreover, we would like to lazily evaluate the function, by storing its results to the disk, and not rerunning the function twice for the same arguments.

Without caching the result (memoization) one would do the following:

```
def complex_computation(arguments):
    ...
    return result

@gen.coroutine
def complex_computation_caller(arguments):
    ...
    result = complex_computation(arguments)
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

Assume to achieve function memoization, we choose **Memory** class from **joblib**. By simply decorating the function with `@mem.cache` the function can easily be memoized:

```
@mem.cache
def complex_computation(arguments):
    ...
    return result
```

where `mem` can be something like `mem = Memory(cachedir=get_cache_dir())`.

Now consider combining the two, where we execute the computationally complex function on an executor:

```
class TaskRunner(object):
    def __init__(self, loop=None, number_of_workers=1):
        self.executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(number_of_workers)
        self.loop = loop or IOLoop.instance()

    @run_on_executor
    def run(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

mem = Memory(cachedir=get_cache_dir())
_runner = TaskRunner(1)

@mem.cache
def complex_computation(arguments):
    ...
    return result

@gen.coroutine
def complex_computation_caller(arguments):
    result = yield _runner.run(complex_computation, arguments)
    ...
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

So the first question is whether the aforementioned approach is technically correct?

Now let's consider the following scenario:

```
@gen.coroutine
def first_coroutine(arguments):
    ...
    result = yield second_coroutine(arguments)
    raise gen.Return(result)

@gen.coroutine
def second_coroutine(arguments):
    ...
    result = yield third_coroutine(arguments)
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

The second question is how one can memoize `second_coroutine`? Is it correct to do something like:

```
@gen.coroutine
def first_coroutine(arguments):
    ...
    mem = Memory(cachedir=get_cache_dir())
    mem_second_coroutine = mem(second_coroutine)
    result = yield mem_second_coroutine(arguments)
    raise gen.Return(result)

@gen.coroutine
def second_coroutine(arguments):
    ...
    result = yield third_coroutine(arguments)
    raise gen.Return(result)
```

**[UPDATE I]** [Caching and reusing a function result in Tornado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374238/caching-and-reusing-a-function-result-in-tornado) discusses using `functools.lru_cache` or `repoze.lru.lru_cache` as a solution for second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Future` objects returned by Tornado coroutines are reusable, so it generally works to use in-memory caches such as `functools.lru_cache`, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374238/caching-and-reusing-a-function-result-in-tornado). Just be sure to put the caching decorator before `@gen.coroutine`.

On-disk caching (which seems to be implied by the `cachedir` argument to `Memory`) is trickier, since `Future` objects cannot generally be written to disk. Your `TaskRunner` example should work, but it's doing something fundamentally different from the others because `complex_calculation` is not a coroutine. Your last example will not work, because it's trying to put the `Future` object in the cache.

Instead, if you want to cache things with a decorator, you'll need a decorator that wraps the inner coroutine with a second coroutine. Something like this:

```
def cached_coroutine(f):
    @gen.coroutine
    def wrapped(*args):
        if args in cache:
            return cache[args]
        result = yield f(*args)
        cache[args] = f
        return result
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes. You're right. I already tested `functools.lru_cache` and it works like a charm. Regarding your example, I assume `cache` is something provided by outer context as you don't seem to be defining a anything inside the outer decorator closure. Nonetheless, your example is perfectly clear for me to grasp the idea. Cheers!